# Regular expression to include all specific pattern and exclude only one case

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working something to exclude some URL.

I want to expect all URLs with the pattern `/google.com/`, except for `/login.google.com/`

So:

- `account.google.com` should pass
- `google.com` should pass
- `google.com/abc` should pass
- `http://google.com` should pass
- `login.google.com` should **not** pass

The code I am trying is

```regex
/^(?!login\.)google\.com/
/^(login)google\.com/
```

but neither is working. Am I missing something?

Comment: What results are you getting with these?

Comment: You originally had this tagged as just JavaScript, and your question looks "JavaScript-ey", but now you have added Java. These are very different languages. Did you only mean one and not the other (I'm guessing just JS), or do you need this for both languages? Also, the `computer-science` tag is way too broad for this question.

Comment: It should be in javascript, I am removing it

Comment: The problem is your understanding of `^`. A lookbehind following a `^` will never match (except in multiline mode). Do you see why?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're trying to match any `google.com` address except ones that begin with `login.`, you need to just add a `.*` prior to the `google`, i.e.

```regex
/^(https?:\/\/)?(?!login\.)([\w-]+\.)?google\.com/
```

Update: Modified based on helpful comments. Not sure what the valid domain name character class is - took a guess at that as being `[\w-]`.  See http://rubular.com/ if you want to play with it.

Comment: Yep, [this passes the test cases](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=^%28%3F!login\.%29.*google\.com&input=account.google.com%20%2F%2Fpass%0Agoogle.com%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fpass%0Agoogle.com%2Fabc%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fpass%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%20%20%2F%2Fpass%0Alogin.google.com%20%20%20%2F%2Fnot%20pass)

Comment: You should throw in an extra `\.` with an optional, e.g. `(.*\.)?` in front of the `google` part to prevent matching `fakegoogle.com` and the like. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: You've incorporated Brian's fix, but that causes `http://google.com` to break. You want [`/^(https?://)?(?!login\.)(.*\.)?google\.com/`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=^%28https%3F%3A%2F%2F%29%3F%28%3F!login\.%29%28.*\.%29%3Fgoogle\.com&input=account.google.com%20%2F%2Fpass%0Agoogle.com%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fpass%0Agoogle.com%2Fabc%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fpass%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%20%20%2F%2Fpass%0Alogin.google.com%20%20%20%2F%2Fnot%20pass%0Afakegoogle.com%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fnot%20pass).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Just noticed that myself, whoops. That's the correct regex.

Comment: :-)  The original post didn't include URLs with protocol information.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin The question says “`http://google.com` should pass”, so yes, they want to handle the protocol.

Comment: I could have sworn that the original post didn't have the http: example in it (because I copy/pasted the examples to Rubular for testing and it's not there now), but I can't see the change in the edit log, so I must have inadvertently deleted it in Rubular.  Oh well.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane and anubhava and Brian (again) - Thanks to you all.  Hopefully I got this right.  If SO let you "split" rep points, I would do so at this point.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work for you:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?!login\.)(?:.+?\.)?google\.com(?:/.*|)$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/z69WSKV9cM

**Javascript syntax:**

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!login\.)(?:.+?\.)?google\.com(?:\/.*|)$/
```

Comment: Since the asker is using JavaScript, it's better to use an regex testing tool that uses the JavaScript regex engine. There is a list of tools for various languages on the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). Thankfully, your regex [still works in JavaScript](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=^%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%2F%2F%29%3F%28%3F!login\.%29%28%3F%3A.%2B%3F\.%29%3Fgoogle\.com\b%28%3F%3A%2F.*|%29%24&input=account.google.com%0Agoogle.com%0Agoogle.com%2Fabc%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%0Aaa.bb.google.com%0Alogin.google.com%0Afakegoogle.com%0A.google.com).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: Good point, Though I didn't use any language specific feature in my regex but I would keep this in mind.

Comment: Since the OP used forward slashes to define the regex, you might want to escape the forward slashes in your code fragment above, as you did in your Rubular example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pattern to match the data listed in the question:

```
/^(account\.)?google\.com/
```

Comment: @Zeta the question doesn't mention matching the protocol part of a URL, just a host/domain name.   (Actually, the question was edited to add that :-/)

Comment: @ajp15243 That wasn't indicated in the description.

Comment: @dsh While you have changed your wording to accurately reflect that your answer applies strictly to only the examples in the question, the stated attempts to specifically exclude `login.` indicate that it is probably safe to say that OP is trying to match anything except `login.google.com`, as opposed to only the list of examples and nothing more as you have done. Nonetheless, OP should have been clear on that point.